# Django template Javascript passing a python variable to a javascript one

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I did create a `python` function called `generate_random_number` that generate a random number between 1 and 9 and compare it to the `id` of each video in my database and return the `url` of the video corresponding to the id matching the random number. Here is the function:

```
from random import randint
from dash_interface.models import Video
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def random_video():
    random_number = randint(1, 9)
    all_videos = Video.objects.all()
    for video in all_videos:
        if video.id == random_number:
           random_url = video.video_url
           return random_url
```

I want to pass `random_url` to a `javascript` variable in a `django` template.

My template looks like this:

```html
<video id="videoplayer" controls></video>

            <script>
                {% load generate_random_number %}
            // setup the video element and attach it to the Dash player
            function setupVideo() {
              var url = " ";
              var context = new Dash.di.DashContext();
              var player = new MediaPlayer(context);
                              player.startup();
                              player.attachView(document.querySelector("#videoplayer"));
                              player.attachSource(url);
            }
            </script>

            <style>
            video {
              width: 60%;
              height: 40%;
            }
            </style>
```

The variable concerned is `url`.

I did a `{% load generate_random_number %}`, but I don't know if I can replace the quotation marks in `url` by `{{ random_url }}`.

Comment: Yes you can do it. `"{{ random_url }}"` will create a string notation of the url that is returned and that string can be stored in any JS variable.

Comment: I did it but I doesn't play any video

Comment: Try inspecting your HTML and debug your JS and make sure if `"{{ random_url }}"` is returning something.

Comment: Where are you calling the `generate_random_number` tag? And why do you think you have something called `random_url` in the template?

Comment: In template you have to specify `var url = "{{ random_video }}"`, you can check it with `console.log(url);` or `alert(url)`, after defining `url`.

Comment: @Daniel I want to use it in the template so I am calling it in the template using load. I don't think that I have anything that's why I am asking.

Comment: But load does not *call* a template tag, it only *loads* it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman when I did search on the internet I didn't find how to call the template tag and I didn't know how to do it ( I am a beginner ) so if you know how could you please tell me

Comment: @A.Arfaoui "when I did search on the internet I didn't find how to call the template tag" => this IS fully documented in Django's official documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#tags

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the javascript code and html code, you could make something like:

```
<script arg = {{ somevar }} src = "/path/to/script"></script>
```

and in the script :

```
var arg = $("script[src='/path/to/script']").attr("arg");
```

If you need that the arg will be updated each a concrete period, you need to make an ajax. If you use the database for persist the arg, you could use Django Channels like a more elegance solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the custom template tag definitions in a `templatetags` folder inside your app. Make sure that `__init__.py` is present in the `templatetags` folder. Your folder structure should be similar to:

```
your_django_app/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        template_tags.py
    views.py
```

And the contents of template_tags.py should be you required tag definition:

```
from random import randint
from dash_interface.models import Video
from django import template

register = template.Library()  

@register.simple_tag
def random_video():
    random_number = randint(1, 9)
    all_videos = Video.objects.all()
    for video in all_videos:
        if video.id == random_number:
           random_url = video.video_url
           return random_url
```

Note: The `templatetags` file should contain the variable named `register`.

After this you can load the template tags in your HTML. Your code will look like:

```
<video id="videoplayer" controls></video>
{% load template_tags %}

            <script>
            // setup the video element and attach it to the Dash player
            function setupVideo() {
              var url = "{% random_video %}";
              var context = new Dash.di.DashContext();
              var player = new MediaPlayer(context);
                              player.startup();
                              player.attachView(document.querySelector("#videoplayer"));
                              player.attachSource(url);
            }
            </script>

            <style>
            video {
              width: 60%;
              height: 40%;
            }
            </style>
```

Comment: I did create a directory called templatetags in my app where I added the generate_random_number and an empty __init__.py I will try to do  the other changes and see if it works

Comment: No I'm pretty sure its the name of the function. You can check if the template tag is working by adding ```alert(url);``` after the line ```var url = "{% random_video %}";```. If its alerting a valid URL then its just the problem of the javascript

Comment: That's strange I remember it being the name of the function. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I am really sorry what you said is correct it's {% random_video %} please edit your answer it was correct

Answer (score 0):

**This is the way I prefer to connect Django templates and JS.**

*You need to import render function:*

**views.py file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from random import randint
from dash_interface.models import Video

def random_video(request):
    random_number = randint(1, 9)
    all_videos = Video.objects.all()
    for video in all_videos:
        if video.id == random_number:
           random_url = video.video_url
           context = {
               "random_url": random_url
           }
           return render(request, "app/video.html", context)
        else:
           return render(request, "app/video.html", {})
```

**video.html**

```
<video id="videoplayer" controls></video>

            <script>
                {% load generate_random_number %}
            // setup the video element and attach it to the Dash player
            function setupVideo() {
              // using the context passed in here.
              var url = {{ random_url|safe }}; 
              var context = new Dash.di.DashContext();
              var player = new MediaPlayer(context);
              player.startup();
              player.attachView(document.querySelector("#videoplayer"));
              player.attachSource(url);
            }
        </script>

        <style>
        video {
          width: 60%;
          height: 40%;
        }
        </style>
```

*What I have done is rendered your HTML page in the Django view and passed your variable inside the context dictionary which is later accessible in your HTML tags or script tags.*

*I also used a **|safe** parameter in the template tag which removes some unwanted strings.*

**Cheers and Hope it helps! I have tried this thing in many of my projects and it has always been a success for me.**